# How to combine rows in a dataframe in a pairwise fashion while applying some function

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, pairwise

I have a dataframe that stores keys as ID, and some numerical values in Val1/Val2:

```
ID    Val1    Val2
id0     10      20
id0     11      19
id1      5       5
id1      1       1
id1      2       4
```

I would like to go over this dataframe and combine the rows pairwise while getting the averages of Val1/Val2 for rows with the same ID. A suffix should be appended to the new row's ID based on which number pair it is.

Here is the resulting dataframe:

```
ID      Val1    Val2
id0_1   10.5    19.5
id1_1   3       3
id1_2   1.5     2.5
```

In this example, there are only 3 rows left. (id0, 10, 20) gets averaged with (id0,11,19) and combined into one row.

(id1,5,5) gets averaged with (id1,1,1,) and (id1,1,1) gets averaged with (id1,2,4) to form 2 remaining rows.

**I can think of an iterative approach to this, but that would be very slow. How could I do this in a proper pythonic/pandas way?**

Code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['ID', 'Val1', 'Val2'], data=[['id0', 10, 20], ['id0', 11, 19], ['id1', 5, 5], ['id1', 1, 1], ['id1', 2, 4]])
```

Comment: You want the mean against the next row within a group by ID?

Comment: can you explain the logic if there is no pair?

Comment: @Umar.H there will always be at least a pair

Comment: @ifly6 no, it should operate on the old data that was there before. so don't take the mean against something that has been averaged already

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `df.rolling` after grouping by `ID`:

```
out = df.groupby('ID').rolling(2).mean() \
        .dropna(how='all').reset_index(level=1, drop=True)

out.index += '_' + out.groupby(level=0).cumcount().add(1).astype(str)
```

```
>>> out
       Val1  Val2
id0_1  10.5  19.5
id1_1   3.0   3.0
id1_2   1.5   2.5
```

Comment: this solution does not handle the '_x' appending that should take place. so id0_1, id1_1, id1_2

Comment: i added another column 'Val3' that i want the same mean logic applied to. when running your snippet the 'Val3' column is not included. can you explain which part of the code needs to be edited?

Comment: You have not to modify anything. `df.groupby` gets all columns. If you want to select specific columns, do `df.groupby('ID')[['Val1', 'Val3']].rolling(...`

Comment: thanks! even though you said df.groupby gets all cols, it was excluding Val3 for me. I just ended up specifying manually `[['Val1','Val2', 'Val3']]`

Comment: It's really weird, it shouldn't be the case. The dataframe `out` takes all columns without exception.